# Is highcharts supported in IE8 compat mode while printing?

Tags: internet-explorer, highcharts

I am facing some problem with highcharts while printing in IE8 compat (browser) mode.The chart is not rendering properly but the title , subtitle, legend and axes are visible. It works perfectly in IE8(browser) mode. Can anybody guide me how to fix this issue.I have tried solving it by setting the meta tag in all possible ways but could not find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Make working example on chrome for example, and try it with jsfiddle.net/xxxx/show/ on IE8 compatibility mode.